# how to find an 8.3 named file on a linux that contains the file

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, filenames

I've gotten myself into a corner - I have really old dBase tables that contain 8.3 filenames that were obviously kept on an old msdos/windows system together with files.

All I have now are the files and the dBase (DBF file) - but the links that connect between rows in the db and the actual files are in 8.3 format. The files and dBase files have been copied over from the old windows machine to the linux machine.

for example the db will have a row containing:

{"fileid" : 1, "dosname" : "APPLE~1.JPG"},
{"fileid" : 2, "dosname" : "APPLE~2.JPG"}

and somewhere in the file directory i may have 
"appletree.JPG" 
and 
"apple computer.JPG" .

how can I tell which is which? is there some kind of logic I can follow (like alphanumeric sorting to tell which is ~1 and which is ~2?)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we are actually talking about 8.3 file names created by some *Windows* ... it isn't too hard.

Microsoft has a nice specification out there that exactly explains how those "longer" filenames are mapped to 8.3 "notation".

See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/142982).

So you can sit down; and you should be able to come up with a mapping tool that well, maps the "long filenames" to their DB row 8.3 cousins.

Edit: as correctly pointed out, the above link is just a description, but not an exact algorithm for the required mapping - but maybe [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/fat/namei_vfat.c?v=4.6#L308) algorithm does the trick for you!

Comment: I've read this - "Windows truncates the file name, if necessary, to six characters and appends a tilde (~) and a digit. For example, each unique file name created ends with "~1." Duplicate file names end with "~2," "~3," and so on. ---- " - I'm missing information when converting from long to 8.3 so a backwards conversion is not possible.

Comment: @NiRR Well, you could run the files on your disk through the algorithm (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/fat/namei_vfat.c?v=4.6#L308) to create the SFN for a given LFN and you'd get the mapping,

Comment: @itisravi Thanks for your input; I updated my answer accordingly. And as you provided such value input; I select your two most valuable answers and upvoted them, too.

Comment: @NiRR I hope this answer is now good enough; if so, consider accepting / upvoting; and everybody is happy ;-)